# How to Implement (Convex) Chance Constraints in Gurobi

Tags: stochastic-processes, convex-optimization

I would like to implement a chance constraint of the form 
$$ \mathbb{P}[a^\text{T}x\leqslant b]\geqslant\alpha$$
where $b\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed, $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector whose entries are iid and normally distributed with mean $\overline{a}$ and variance $\Sigma$ (that is, $a\sim\mathcal{N}(\overline{a},\Sigma)$), and $\alpha>1/2$ (so that the resulting problem is convex). It is well known that this constraint is equivalent to
$$ F^{-1}(\alpha)\|\Sigma^{1/2}x\|_2\leqslant-\overline{a}^\text{T}x+b $$
which is a [second-order cone constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming#Example:_Stochastic_second-order_cone_programming) (SOC constraint). Moreover, [Gurobi advertises that is has an SOCP solver](http://www.gurobi.com/resources/seminars-and-videos/gurobi-quadratic-constraints-webinar). However, [their documentation](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/constraints.html#subsubsection:QuadraticConstraints) only advertises being able to solve the following three types of constraints:
$$ x^\text{T}Qx+q^\text{T}x+b\leqslant0 \text{ where }Q\text{ is s.p.d.} $$
$$ x^\text{T}x\leqslant y^2, y\geqslant0 $$
$$ x^\text{T}x\leqslant yz, y,z\geqslant0 $$
I cannot wrangle the chance constraint into any of these three forms (I will be happy to show my attempts if desired). This seems like it should certainly be possible...how can I handle this in Gurobi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2nd form:

$w =  F^{-1}(\alpha) \Sigma^{1/2}x$

$y = -\overline{a}^\text{T}x+b $

$w^Tw \le y^2$

$ y \ge 0$

which collectively is equivalent to $ F^{-1}(\alpha)\|\Sigma^{1/2}x\|_2\leqslant-\overline{a}^\text{T}x+b $

Comment: Ahhh I was hung up on the sign of $y$, but I see that $y\geqslant0$ does not affect the feasible region. That was my major concern with that approach. Thank you

Comment: Or just use CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY, or similar convex optimization modeling tool, and you can enter the constraint essentially as you originally wrote, and specify GUROBI or another solver to solve it. They handle the transformations to put the problem into a form which the solver accepts and transform the result back to the form you entered.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have never used CVX but now might be the time to start!

Comment: @David M.   Hello ,you say in your question ,when $\alpha > 0.5 $ then problem is convex, I have this question ( why problem is convex when $\alpha >0.5$) please help, thanks

Comment: Can you introduce me a book it site?

Comment: @linkhochon The result was first proven in a 1958 paper by Charnes et al. Otherwise it’s not so hard to prove yourself using the fact that norms are convex functions.

Comment: @David M. Thanks a lot